# "Running Sum" Using a Date Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm currently in the midst of writing up a SQL Query in Management Studio 2012.  Pretty much I need to incorporate a Date parameter that will gather the total sum of `TotalContributors`, `TotalCharts`, etc. up until the Date that is given.

```
DECLARE @DateEnd DATETIME = '06/13/2014'
DECLARE @GeneralStats TABLE (
       TotalPapers INT,
   SiteID BIGINT,
   SiteEventGroupID INT,
   EventCreateDate DATETIME,
   AssignmentType VARCHAR(20),
   AssignmentTypeIndex INT
    );
INSERT INTO @GeneralStats
        ( TotalPapers ,
         SiteID ,
         SiteEventGroupID,
     EventCreateDate,
     AssignmentType,
     AssignmentTypeIndex
        )
SELECT 
   TotalPapers ,
   SiteID,
   SiteEventGroupID,
   EventCreateDate,
CASE
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN '1-4 Papers'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN '5-9 Papers'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 10 AND 24 THEN '10-24 Papers'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 25 AND 49 THEN '25-49 Papers'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 50 AND 99 THEN '50-99 Papers'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 100 AND 249 THEN '100-249 Papers'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 250 AND 499 THEN '250-499 Papers'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN '500-1000 Papers'  
    WHEN TotalPapers > 1000 THEN 'Greater 1000'
END AssignmentType,
CASE
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN '1'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN '2'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 10 AND 24 THEN '3'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 25 AND 49 THEN '4'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 50 AND 99 THEN '5'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 100 AND 249 THEN '6'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 250 AND 499 THEN '7'  
    WHEN TotalPapers BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN '8'  
    WHEN TotalPapers > 1000 THEN '9'
END AssignmentTypeIndex
FROM (
SELECT
    COUNT(c.PaperID) TotalPapers,
    c.SiteID, 
    wfseg.SiteEventGroupID,
    wfse.EventCreateDate
FROM
    Sites s 
    INNER JOIN Papers c ON s.SiteID = c.SiteID
    LEFT JOIN WFSiteEvents wfse ON s.SiteID = wfse.SiteID AND EventStatusID IN (1,2)
    LEFT JOIN WFSiteEventTypes wfset ON wfse.EventTypeID = wfset.EventTypeID
    LEFT JOIN WFSiteEventGroups wfseg ON wfset.SiteEventGroupID = wfseg.SiteEventGroupID
WHERE
    c.SiteID <> 110
GROUP BY
    c.SiteID, 
    wfseg.SiteEventGroupID,
    wfse.EventCreateDate
) d
ORDER BY SiteID

SELECT  
 Main.CreateDate,
 Main.AssignmentType,
    Main.Contributors as TotalContributors,
    Main.Papers as TotalPapers,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Main.[%]) [Total%],
    ISNULL(Type1.Contributors, 0) Type1Contributors ,
    ISNULL(Type1.Papers,0) Type1Papers, 
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Type1.[%]),0) [Type1%],
    ISNULL(Type2.Contributors, 0) Type2Contributors ,
    ISNULL(Type2.Papers, 0) Type2Papers ,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Type2.[%]),0) [Type2%],
    ISNULL(Type3.Contributors,0) Type3Contributors ,
    ISNULL(Type3.Papers, 0) Type3Papers ,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Type3.[%]), 0) [Type3%],
    ISNULL(Type4.Contributors, 0) Type4Contributors ,
    ISNULL(Type4.Papers, 0) Type4Papers ,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Type4.[%]), 0) [Type4%],
    ISNULL(Type5.Contributors, 0) Type5Contributors ,
    ISNULL(Type5.Papers, 0) Type5Papers ,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Type5.[%]), 0) [Type5%]
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar,EventCreateDate,101) as CreateDate,
    AssignmentTypeIndex,
    AssignmentType, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT SiteID) Contributors, 
    SUM(TotalPapers) Papers, 
    SUM(TotalPapers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(TotalPapers) FROM @GeneralStats)  [%]
FROM @GeneralStats
WHERE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,EventCreateDate, 101) <= @DateEnd
GROUP BY AssignmentType, AssignmentTypeIndex, CONVERT(varchar,EventCreateDate,101)
) Main
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar,EventCreateDate,101) as CreateDate,
    AssignmentType, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT SiteID) Contributors, 
    SUM(TotalPapers) Papers, 
    SUM(TotalPapers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(TotalPapers) FROM @GeneralStats WHERE SiteEventGroupID = 3)  [%]
FROM @GeneralStats
WHERE SiteEventGroupID = 3
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,EventCreateDate, 101) <= @DateEnd
GROUP BY AssignmentType, CONVERT(varchar,EventCreateDate,101)
)Type1 ON  Main.AssignmentType = Type1.AssignmentType
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar,EventCreateDate,101) as CreateDate,
    AssignmentType, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT SiteID) Contributors, 
    SUM(TotalPapers) Papers, 
    SUM(TotalPapers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(TotalPapers) FROM @GeneralStats WHERE SiteEventGroupID = 4)  [%]
FROM @GeneralStats
WHERE SiteEventGroupID = 4
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,EventCreateDate, 101) <= @DateEnd
GROUP BY AssignmentType, CONVERT(varchar,EventCreateDate,101)
)Type2 ON  Main.AssignmentType = Type2.AssignmentType
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar,EventCreateDate,101) as CreateDate,
    AssignmentType, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT SiteID) Contributors, 
    SUM(TotalPapers) Papers, 
    SUM(TotalPapers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(TotalPapers) FROM @GeneralStats WHERE SiteEventGroupID = 2)  [%]
FROM @GeneralStats
WHERE SiteEventGroupID = 2
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,EventCreateDate, 101) <= @DateEnd
GROUP BY AssignmentType, CONVERT(varchar,EventCreateDate,101)
)Type3 ON  Main.AssignmentType = Type3.AssignmentType
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar,EventCreateDate,101) as CreateDate,
    AssignmentType, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT SiteID) Contributors, 
    SUM(TotalPapers) Papers, 
    SUM(TotalPapers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(TotalPapers) FROM @GeneralStats WHERE SiteEventGroupID = 9)  [%]
FROM @GeneralStats
WHERE SiteEventGroupID = 9
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,EventCreateDate, 101) <= @DateEnd
GROUP BY AssignmentType, CONVERT(varchar,EventCreateDate,101) 
)Type4 ON  Main.AssignmentType = Type4.AssignmentType
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar,EventCreateDate,101) as CreateDate,
    AssignmentType, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT SiteID) Contributors, 
    SUM(TotalPapers) Papers, 
    SUM(TotalPapers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(TotalPapers) FROM @GeneralStats WHERE SiteEventGroupID = 8)  [%]
FROM @GeneralStats
WHERE SiteEventGroupID = 8
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR,EventCreateDate, 101) <= @DateEnd
GROUP BY AssignmentType, CONVERT(varchar,EventCreateDate,101) 
)Type5 ON  Main.AssignmentType = Type5.AssignmentType

ORDER BY AssignmentTypeIndex
```

I took a stab at it adding in `DECLARE @DateEnd DATETIME = '06/13/2014'` and adding the `@DateEnd` throughout but it doesn't really give me the results I want nor in the correct format.

**How it comes out now:**

```
CreateDate | AssignmentType | TotalContributors | TotalPapers | Total% | Type1Contributors | Type1Papers | Type1% | Type2Contributors | Type2Papers | Type2% | Type3Contributors | Type3Papers | Type3% | Type4Contributors | Type4Papers | Type4% |  Type5Contributors | Type5Papers | Type5%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
04/28/2014 | 1-4 Papers     | 11329             | 17478       | 2.24   | 19                | 42          | 0.02   | 6                 | 11          | 0.01   | 4                 | 9           | 0.00   | 1                 | 1           | 0.00%  |   7                | 10          | 0.09 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
04/28/2014 | 1-4 Papers     | 11329             | 17478       | 2.24   | 19                | 42          | 0.02   | 6                 | 11          | 0.01   | 4                 | 9           | 0.00   | 1                 | 1           | 0.00%  |   3                | 8           | 0.07 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
04/28/2014 | 1-4 Papers     | 11329             | 17478       | 2.24   | 19                | 42          | 0.02   | 6                 | 11          | 0.01   | 4                 | 9           | 0.00   | 1                 | 1           | 0.00%  |   2                | 7           | 0.06

-- etc. Running it actually takes FOREVER and I've never seen the end of it
```

**How I'd like it to look like:**

```
CreateDate | AssignmentType | TotalContributors | TotalPapers | Total% | Type1Contributors | Type1Papers | Type1% | Type2Contributors | Type2Papers | Type2% | Type3Contributors | Type3Papers | Type3% | Type4Contributors | Type4Papers | Type4% |  Type5Contributors | Type5Papers | Type5%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
06/13/2014 | 1-4 Papers     | --Total#upto6/13  -> for all rows 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
06/13/2014 | 5-9 Papers     | --Total#upto6/13  -> for all rows 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
06/13/2014 | 10-24 Papers   | --Total#upto6/13  -> for all rows 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
06/13/2014 | 25-49 Papers   | --Total#upto6/13  -> for all rows 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
06/13/2014 | 50-99 Papers   | --Total#upto6/13  -> for all rows
```

Comment: This is one heck of a query...

Comment: Can you set up a bit of sample table data on SQL fiddle or post some here so we can work with some samples?

Comment: It also occurs to me that you will get inaccurate numbers, as you're joining Papers to sites, then sites to events, multiplying the Papers.PaperID count by the number of Events. Is there an ID that links Papers to WFSiteEvents?

Comment: Well I guess I could cut that part out since Papers has a SiteID and WFSiteEvents has a SiteID as well - so they can link from there

Comment: Also made a SQL Fiddle (or tried too) and it's preeettttyy hefty - However, the SQL Query I put in here (which works in Management Studio )is giving me a problem in Fiddle and I'm not sure where the disconnect could be....

[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/976ee/2)

Comment: It seems Fiddle has problems with Table Variables, and I'm unsure why, but I can use your schema (I'll add a new table and link the result) to develop a solution for you. I still think that multiplying the Papers by Events (same diff unless Papers has a link to events's ID.) isn't quite right, but if you're wanting that, I can continue.

Comment: We'd actually have to keep WFSiteEvents because WFSiteEvents has the EventID to link with the WFSiteEventGroups.

Comment: I'm not suggesting removing it. I was hoping that Papers had a foreign key to WFSiteEvents.

Comment: Well there is a way to actually connect the two directly. Papers has SiteID and WFSiteEvents also has a SiteID so Papers.SiteID=WFSiteEvents.SiteID

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in the following manner, this is a simplistic approach to aid in understanding.

Assume you have a table as follows, named `tblLedger`:

```
ID     | Date        | Amount
1      | 2014-01-01  | 100.00
2      | 2014-01-15  | 75.00
3      | 2014-01-15  | -25.00
```

Query:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Date, T1.Amount, SUM(T2.Amount) AS 'Balance'
FROM tblLedger T1
JOIN tblLedger T2 ON T1.ID>=T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.Date, T1.Amount
```

[Here is a fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4b66/1).

Answer (score 0):

So I did a bit on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40278/20). This should run relatively quickly. Take note of the extra tables created, but mostly we are taking several sub-typed queries of the main data set (much like your approach), but it's doing 15 columns of work in 6 queries and 6 aggregates rather than 6 queries and 15 aggregates. The heavy hitter should be the Pivot operator after that. Here's the explicit...Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Sites 
(
  SiteID INT
 );

INSERT INTO Sites (SiteID)
VALUES (12345),(67890),(09876),(54321),(13579),(24680),(12457),(23679),(09126),(12094);

CREATE TABLE Papers
(
  SiteID INT,
  PaperID INT
 );

INSERT INTO Papers (SiteID,PaperID)
VALUES (12345,123456),(12345,789012),(12345,165655),(12345,165656),
(67890,165676),(67890,165677),(67890,165657),(67890,165658),(67890,165659),(67890,165660),
(09876,165661),(09876,165662),(09876,165663),(09876,165664),(09876,165665),
(54321,165666),(54321,165667),(54321,165668),
(13579,165669),
(24680,165670),
(12457,165671),
(23679,165672),(23679,165673),(23679,165674),(23679,165675),(23679,165702),(23679,165703),(23679,165704),(23679,165705),(23679,165706),(23679,165707),(23679,165708),
(09126,165709),(09126,165710),(09126,165711),(09126,165712),(09126,165713),(09126,165714),(09126,165715),(09126,165716),(09126,165717),(09126,165718),(09126,165719),
(12094,165720),(12094,165721),(12094,165722),(12094,165723);

CREATE TABLE WFSiteEvents
(
  SiteEventID INT,
  SiteID INT,
  EventStatusID INT,
  EventTypeID INT,
  EventCreateDate DATETIME 
 );

INSERT INTO WFSiteEvents (SiteEventID,SiteID,EventStatusID,EventTypeID,EventCreateDate)
VALUES (21487,12345,1,1220,'2014-06-04 15:35:19.027'),
(21483,12345,3,1000,'2014-06-04 15:30:36.000'),
(28000,12345,8,1000,'2014-04-28 08:00:00.000'),
(16660,67890,1,1210,'2014-04-28 08:00:00.000'),
(18742,09876,1,1103,'2014-05-28 13:47:51.033'),
(28002,09876,3,1000,'2014-04-28 08:00:00.000'),
(25575,54321,1,1103,'2014-06-16 10:14:54.030'),
(28007,54321,3,1000,'2014-04-28 08:00:00.000'),
(25572,54321,3,1000,'2014-06-16 10:11:04.000'),
(11345,54321,8,1305,'2014-04-29 16:44:56.000'),
(25082,13579,1,1103,'2014-06-13 09:59:04.690'),
(28013,13579,3,1000,'2014-04-28 08:00:00.000'),
(17716,13579,3,1101,'2014-05-23 10:49:14.000'),
(11330,24680,1,1305,'2014-04-29 15:55:24.440'),
(28006,24680,3,1000,'2014-04-28 08:00:00.000'),
(25097,12457,1,1220,'2014-06-13 10:15:31.047'),
(18664,12457,3,1210,'2014-05-28 12:08:05.000'),
(18507,12457,3,1000,'2014-05-28 09:03:44.000'),
(28408,12457,8,1000,'2014-04-28 08:00:00.000'),
(49182,23679,1,1405,'2014-05-23 10:49:14.000'),
(59283,23679,3,1000,'2014-04-28 08:00:00.000'),
(17589,09126,1,1211,'2014-05-22 16:36:54.870'),
(17587,09126,3,1211,'2014-05-22 16:36:42.000'),
(17203,09126,3,1220,'2014-05-22 08:51:14.000'),
(82253,09126,8,1000,'2014-04-28 08:00:00.000'),
(17186,12094,1,1101,'2014-05-22 08:28:59.500'),
(82254,12094,3,1000,'2014-04-28 08:00:00.000');

CREATE TABLE WFSiteEventTypes
(
  EventTypeID INT,
  SiteEventGroupID INT
 );

INSERT INTO WFSiteEventTypes(EventTypeID,SiteEventGroupID)
VALUES (1220,4),
(1000,1),
(1103,2),
(1210,3),
(1305,8),
(1405,9),
(1211,3);

CREATE TABLE WFSiteEventGroups
(
  SiteEventGroupID INT
 );

INSERT INTO WFSiteEventGroups (SiteEventGroupID)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(6),(7),(8),(9)

CREATE TABLE PaperAssignmentDivisions(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
  , MinAssign INT NOT NULL
  , MaxAssign INT
);
INSERT INTO PaperAssignmentDivisions (MinAssign, MaxAssign) VALUES
    (1,4)
  , (5,9)
  , (10,24)
  , (25,49)
  , (50,99)
  , (100,249)
  , (250,499)
  , (500,1000)
  , (1001,NULL);

CREATE TABLE SiteEventGroupIDToType (
    SiteEventGroupID INT
  , Type INT
  );
INSERT INTO SiteEventGroupIDToType VALUES
    (3,1)
  , (4,2)
  , (2,3)
  , (9,4)
  , (8,5);

CREATE TABLE GeneralStats (
    TotalPapers INT,
    SiteID BIGINT,
    Type INT,
    EventCreateDate DATETIME,
    AssignmentType VARCHAR(20),
    AssignmentTypeIndex INT
);

INSERT INTO GeneralStats
  (
  TotalPapers ,
  SiteID ,
  Type,
  EventCreateDate,
  AssignmentType,
  AssignmentTypeIndex
  )
SELECT 
    TotalPapers ,
    SiteID,
    stt.Type,
    EventCreateDate,
    CASE
        WHEN MaxAssign IS NULL THEN 'Greater Than ' + (SELECT CAST(MAX(MaxAssign) AS VARCHAR(6)) FROM PaperAssignmentDivisions)
        ELSE CAST(MinAssign AS VARCHAR(6)) + '-' + CAST(MaxAssign AS VARCHAR(6)) + ' Papers'  
    END AssignmentType,
    pad.ID AssignmentTypeIndex
FROM (
    SELECT
        COUNT(c.PaperID) TotalPapers,
        c.SiteID, 
        wfseg.SiteEventGroupID,
        wfse.EventCreateDate
    FROM
        Sites s 
        INNER JOIN Papers c ON s.SiteID = c.SiteID
        LEFT JOIN WFSiteEvents wfse ON s.SiteID = wfse.SiteID AND EventStatusID IN (1,2)
        LEFT JOIN WFSiteEventTypes wfset ON wfse.EventTypeID = wfset.EventTypeID
        LEFT JOIN WFSiteEventGroups wfseg ON wfset.SiteEventGroupID = wfseg.SiteEventGroupID
    WHERE
        c.SiteID <> 110
    GROUP BY
        c.SiteID, 
        wfseg.SiteEventGroupID,
        wfse.EventCreateDate
    ) d
  INNER JOIN PaperAssignmentDivisions pad ON TotalPapers BETWEEN pad.MinAssign AND ISNULL(pad.MaxAssign,2147483647)
  INNER JOIN SiteEventGroupIDToType stt ON stt.SiteEventGroupID = d.SiteEventGroupID
ORDER BY SiteID
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    AssignmentType
  , ISNULL(TotalContributers,0) AS TotalContributers
  , ISNULL(TotalPapers,0) AS TotalPapers
  , ISNULL([Total%],0) AS [Total%]
  , ISNULL(Type1Contributers,0) AS Type1Contributers
  , ISNULL(Type1Papers,0) AS Type1Papers
  , ISNULL([Type1%],0) AS [Type1%]
  , ISNULL(Type2Contributers,0) AS Type2Contributers
  , ISNULL(Type2Papers,0) AS Type2Papers
  , ISNULL([Type2%],0) AS [Type2%]
  , ISNULL(Type3Contributers,0) AS Type3Contributers
  , ISNULL(Type3Papers,0) AS Type3Papers
  , ISNULL([Type3%],0) AS [Type3%]
  , ISNULL(Type4Contributers,0) AS Type4Contributers
  , ISNULL(Type4Papers,0) AS Type4Papers
  , ISNULL([Type4%],0) AS [Type4%]
  , ISNULL(Type5Contributers,0) AS Type5Contributers
  , ISNULL(Type5Papers,0) AS Type5Papers
  , ISNULL([Type5%],0) AS [Type5%]

FROM (
  SELECT
    'TotalContributers' AS AttributeName
    , COUNT(DISTINCT SiteID) AS AttributeValue
    , ID AS AssignmentTypeIndex
    , CASE
        WHEN MaxAssign IS NULL THEN 'Greater Than ' + (SELECT CAST(MAX(MaxAssign) AS VARCHAR(6)) FROM PaperAssignmentDivisions)
        ELSE CAST(MinAssign AS VARCHAR(6)) + '-' + CAST(MaxAssign AS VARCHAR(6)) + ' Papers'  
    END AS AssignmentType
  FROM PaperAssignmentDivisions
    LEFT JOIN GeneralStats ON ID = Type
  WHERE EventCreateDate <= (SELECT MAX(EventCreateDate-1) FROM GeneralStats)
  GROUP BY MinAssign, MaxAssign, ID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'TotalPapers' AS AttributeName
    , SUM(TotalPapers) AS AttributeValue
    , AssignmentTypeIndex
    , AssignmentType
  FROM GeneralStats A
  WHERE EventCreateDate <= (SELECT MAX(EventCreateDate-1) FROM GeneralStats)
  GROUP BY AssignmentTypeIndex, AssignmentType
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Total%' AS AttributeName
    , SUM(TotalPapers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(TotalPapers)*1.0 FROM GeneralStats B) AS AttributeValue
    , AssignmentTypeIndex
    , AssignmentType
  FROM GeneralStats A
  WHERE EventCreateDate <= (SELECT MAX(EventCreateDate-1) FROM GeneralStats)
  GROUP BY AssignmentTypeIndex, AssignmentType
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Type' +
    CAST(Type AS VARCHAR(2))
    + 'Contributers' AS AttributeName
    , COUNT(DISTINCT SiteID) AS AttributeValue
    , AssignmentTypeIndex
    , AssignmentType
  FROM GeneralStats A
  WHERE EventCreateDate <= (SELECT MAX(EventCreateDate-1) FROM GeneralStats)
  GROUP BY Type, AssignmentTypeIndex, AssignmentType
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Type' +
    CAST(Type AS VARCHAR(2))
    + 'Papers' AS AttributeName
    , SUM(TotalPapers) AS AttributeValue
    , AssignmentTypeIndex
    , AssignmentType
  FROM GeneralStats A
  WHERE EventCreateDate <= (SELECT MAX(EventCreateDate-1) FROM GeneralStats)
  GROUP BY Type, AssignmentTypeIndex, AssignmentType
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'Type' +
    CAST(Type AS VARCHAR(2))
    + '%' AS AttributeName
    , SUM(TotalPapers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(TotalPapers)*1.0 FROM GeneralStats B WHERE A.Type = B.Type) AS AttributeValue
    , AssignmentTypeIndex
    , AssignmentType
  FROM GeneralStats A
  WHERE EventCreateDate <= (SELECT MAX(EventCreateDate-1) FROM GeneralStats)
  GROUP BY Type, AssignmentTypeIndex, AssignmentType
  ) P
  PIVOT (
    SUM(AttributeValue) FOR AttributeName IN
    (TotalContributers,Type1Contributers,Type2Contributers,Type3Contributers,Type4Contributers,Type5Contributers
    ,TotalPapers,Type1Papers,Type2Papers,Type3Papers,Type4Papers,Type5Papers
    ,[Total%],[Type1%],[Type2%],[Type3%],[Type4%],[Type5%]
    )
    ) PVT
ORDER BY AssignmentTypeIndex;
```